# Java problem - RHEL

Tags: rhel, java

I have RHEL in a test environment and I wanted to install a program that initiates a script that mandates java. The script tests for Java binaries folder.

I tried first to choose the `java/bin` directory but it said there are no executables in that directory. I tried many things including installing and uninstalling Java. Now I realized I should choose the parent Java folder that has `bin/` and `lib/` as child directories. When I tried to choose this directory now it says the JRE is not compatible with the software I am trying to install.

The software I want to install uses 32bit of Java. I think the one I have now is 64 bit Java.

I downloaded the 32bit version of Java 1.7 and installed it by `rpm` and it said it is installed successfully but I can't actually find it. I get same problem when I try to run my script that java is not compatible.

How can I make sure that Java is installed in 32bit not in 64bit in the desired location?

There is a java file in `/etc/alternatives/java_sdk/bin` but when I try to issue `java -version` I get:

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./java -version
Error: could not find libjava.so
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

Comment: This is really funny. Java was created to avoid architecture issues and then, some troll company/programmer creates a Java-based software that requires 32bit Java instead of using the system one...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
alternatives --config java
```

and choose version of Java you want to use.